# Is it possible to get 21007 status code by verifying receipt in live app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, sandbox, production-environment, auto-renewable

For a user i am getting status code 21007 by verifying in-app receipt. 21007 is for sandbox but my app is live it means its in production mode. And for rest of user i am not getting any error.

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple doc :

> Always verify your receipt with the production URL first If you are
>   doing receipt validation, be sure to verify your receipt with the
>   production URL (https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt) first.
>   This applies even in the case where your app is used in the sandbox
>   environment. App Review will review the production version of your app
>   in the sandbox. When your app processes the receipt, it must be
>   capable of detecting the 21007 receipt status code and sending the
>   receipt to the sandbox receipt validation server
>   (https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt). Once your app is
>   approved and running in the production environment, sending the
>   receipt to the production server first is the correct action.

For more info [Check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2387/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014795-CH1-BEST_PRACTICES-ALWAYS_VERIFY_YOUR_RECEIPT_WITH_THE_PRODUCTION_URL_FIRST)